# how to group array by given month and sum of total?

Tags: php

**I want to get result as sum of total and group by month,
my array look like:**

```
Array
    (
 [0] => Array
 (
 [order_no] => 222
 [month] => Aug-22
 [totalAmount] => 2305
 ) 
[1] => Array
([order_no] => 333
[month] => Aug-22
[totalAmount] => 945
)
[2] => Array
(
[order_no] => 1
[month] => Sep-22
[totalAmount] => 945
)
[3] => Array
(
[order_no] => 111
[month] => Sep-22
[totalAmount] => 2305
)
)
```

What I am trying to do:
I want to group these data by MONTH and return the sum

**Expected Result:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[month] => Aug-22
[totalAmount] => 3254
)
[1] => Array
(
[month] => Sep-22
[totalAmount] => 3254
)
)
```

Comment: Please post the code you already have along with any errors you might get. How do you get the total of 3254?

Comment: Please also use `var_export()` instead of `var_dump()/print_r()` when posting the original array. That will output it as valid PHP code, which helps us when trying to reproduce the issue or write answers.

Comment: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'order_no' => 222,
    'month' => 'Aug-22',
    'totalAmount' => 2305,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'order_no' => 333,
    'month' => 'Aug-22',
    'totalAmount' => 945,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'order_no' => 1,
    'month' => 'Sep-22',
    'totalAmount' => 945,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'order_no' => 111,
    'month' => 'Sep-22',
    'totalAmount' => 2305,
  ),
)

Comment: The title is misleading. It is not grouped and aggregated by months but by days. https://3v4l.org/85eAi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is classic problem to use `array_reduce` function:

```
<?php
$arr = [
    ["order_no" => 222, "month" => "Aug-22", "totalAmount" => 2305],
    ["order_no" => 333, "month" => "Aug-22", "totalAmount" => 945],
    ["order_no" => 1, "month" => "Sep-22", "totalAmount" => 945],
    ["order_no" => 111, "month" => "Sep-22", "totalAmount" => 2305],
];

$res = array_reduce(
    $arr,
    function($acc, $order) {
        if (isset($acc[$order['month']])) {
            $acc[$order['month']]['totalAmount'] += $order['totalAmount'];
        } else {
            $acc[$order['month']] = [
                "month" => $order['month'], "totalAmount" => $order['totalAmount']
            ];
        }
        return $acc;
    },
    []
);

print_r($res);
```

[run php online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/1ba4943084ce648776f3237ebc73a54d/)